# Permission denied on www-data deleting directory

Tags: permissions, apache2, php

I have a folder `/var/www/web/images/173`.

`$ ls -hal`

```
drwxrwxrwx 4 www-data www-data 524K Mar 30 23:11 173
```

Folder 173 has owner and group www-data and permissions 777, just for debugging purposes because I am hopeless. All 4 files in the folder have same permissions and owner as the 173 folder www-data:www-data and 777.

When I run PHP script line `system("rm -rf /var/www/web/images/173")` I get:

`rm: cannot remove '/var/www/web/images/173': Permission denied`

I tried different approach from shell `$ sudo -u www-data rm -rf /var/www/web/images/173` and I still get permission denied.

Is there some other system setting that prevents user `www-data` to execute `rm` command? This does not look like PHP problem, because not even direct command in shell can delete the file.

My www-data line in `/etc/passwd`:

```
www-data:x:33:33:www-data:/var/www:/usr/sbin/nologin
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check the permissions on parent folder (images). I suppose, changing the permision/ownership on "images" folder for www-data, 755 should solve the problem.

Comment: Well funny thing, you gave me one idea, `images` folder was already 777 to, but when I changed `web` folder to 755 it did the trick. I am not very happy about having to grant write permissions two levels up, I still do not get it, I always thought parent folder needs to be granted write permissions to be able to delete inside.

Comment: To delete a file or directory, you must be able to lookup the path, which includes the `web` folder.

Comment: @OlafDietsche OK, now I get it `173` is part of `images` and if I want to change anything in `images` I need write access to `web`, it all confused me because 173 has a lot of subfolders and I did not count up correctly. Vote up.

Comment: @Mike You don't need write access to `web`, but either read or execute permission, in order to traverse the path from root to `images` and `173`. In order to delete something from `images`, you need write access to `images`.

Comment: You are right on execute, 755 on `web` were enough to execute `sudo -u www-data rm -rf /var/www/web/images/173` but jsut read permissions for `web` did not do.